# MYSQL -- *time to query one column* is proportional to *number of rows AND columns in the table*?

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb, long-integer

I've got a 45Gb table with ~76M rows and 150 columns.

When I run the following simple query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE `column_of_interest` IS NOT NULL
```

It takes 850 seconds to return the result. I can see that the mysql process reads the disk at ~40Mo/second the entire time. This means that it goes through almost the entire data stored in the table, despite the fact that it only needs to know about one column.

I assume that if it could read the data of that column specifically, it would be >100X faster (since there are 150 columns).

Is there any way to allow MySQL to read a single column? Table information is provided below.

Thanks for your feedback,

All the best,

Emmanuel

Using EXPLAIN on the query I get:

> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'table_name', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   '76628126', 'Using where'

The engine is InnoDB

I use INT / FLOAT / ENUM / CHAR / VARCHAR(1) to VARCHAR(30) types in the columns

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your table?

Comment: can you just `select count(id) from my_table`; one column (id, or something else), not `*` ?

Comment: You may of course have perfectly legitimate reasons for that design, but 150 columns does seem like quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on your `column_of_interest` column.

```
CREATE INDEX my_tab_col_of_int ON my_table (column_of_interest);
```

It will take a while initially to set up this index. During that time `my_table` will be *unavailable*.

After that the query you've shown will run much faster. That's because indexes are organized in ways that allow rapid querying. Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

**Notice** that `COUNT(colname)` is *slower* in most cases than `COUNT(*)`. The latter expression simply has to know how many rows are in the table. The former has to look at `colname` to exclude null values. It takes longer.

Comment: I confirm that SELECT(colname) is slower, albeit not much. I thought of creating an index but this is not really answering my question, which is "how to allow mysql to make a **full column scan** rather than a **full table scan**"? Since data is naturally organized in columns it seems intuitive that it should be feasible. I do not like the idea of having 150 indexes ...

Comment: Indexes *are* MySQL's way of allowing the database engine to use a subset of columns to satisfy queries. That being said, a full index scan is not a great thing any more than a full table scan is. If your indexes are planned correctly, their effect on query performance can be the next best thing to magic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the select with no cache and getting only the column you want, like:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(column_of_interest) FROM my_table WHERE `column_of_interest` IS NOT NULL
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Comment: If the column is not indexed, that would still need a full table scan.

Comment: True. We're depending on his db structure now :P

Answer (score 0):

There are "column stores" that do store each column separately (sort of).  MySQL does not have such an Engine.  InfoBright is such a 3rd party engine.  And, yes, your query (even without an index) might be 100x faster in such an engine.

I agree with Ollie's comments.  However, in 5.6 (in certain cases) it is possible to add an index without locking the table.  Also `pt-online-schema-update` can do such.

Also, any existing composite index that includes `column_of_interest` would have been used.  Your explain implied that there was none.

**Edit** (More notes, based on title)

If the 45GB is not cached, then the time is proportional to reading 45GB of disk.  If it is all cached, the time is proportional to 76M (rows) -- each row must be accessed, then the one column in question must be extracted.  There may be a slight shortcut because you are testing for `NULL`.  There is some debate about whether the 100th column is slower to fetch than the 1st; but the difference, if any, is minor.

Cached vs uncached is typically 1:10 speed ratio.